# WCF Webservice crash..need to know the cause from memory dump

Tags: wcf

We recently had an issue with one of our WCF webservice crashing in our production environment. We had the memory dump during the crash and we get the following stack trace when we debugged using windbg

> ****Exception object: 000000000a1e5db8 Exception type:   System.ObjectDisposedException Message:          Cannot access a
>   disposed object. InnerException:  `enter code here` 
>   ****StackTrace (generated):
>          System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfClosed()+0xfb2737
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CleanupChannelCollections()+0x37
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnAbort()+0x78
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()+0x28e
>   System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel+SessionIdleManager.TimerCallback()+0x6c
>   System_Runtime_DurableInstancing_ni!System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler+ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x71
>   System_Runtime_DurableInstancing_ni!System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0xdbc70
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32,
>   UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x96**** StackTraceString:
>    HResult: 80131622 StackTraceString:  HResult:
>   80131622****

Could someone give more insight into this exception on when this would occur.

The WCF webservice was running on a windows 2008 server using .net framework 4.0.

Other details:

```
ConcurrencyMode = Multiple
InstanceContextMode = PerSession
```

Our webservice makes calls to several other wcf services. The binding & behaviour information for those are as follows.

```
 <behavior name="NAME">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="10`enter code here`00"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="655360"/>
    </behavior>    
        <binding name="NAME" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="50" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="10485760" maxConnections="150" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="None" />
            </security>
        </binding>
```

Comment: This does not seem complete...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ryadavilli... Is the stack trace incomplete? or the information I provided incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your service code is somehow creating a condition where a disposed WCF `ServiceChannel` instance is being accessed again. It's not clear whether this is happening in a WCF service proxy your service uses to invoke another WCF service or the channel the service is using to respond to client requests. For proper proxy instance disposal, look at this good post on the ["by design" behavior of the `Dispose` method](http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidBarrett/archive/2007/11/22/117058.aspx).

You should describe more about the service configuration such as the `InstanceContextMode` and `ConcurrencyMode` settings and the `serviceModel` configuration to get a better answer.